# call a .xib on CCLayer

Tags: uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm making an app that capture a selected Image from PhotoLibrary and put it on a CCSprite, My problem is: The Images are too large and I can't decrease the size, so I want to add some UIViewController or a .Xib with the size of CCSprite and put the Image on .Xib.

Comment: How do you expect .xib to help you with large size of image?

Comment: You mean you want to create a UIImageView programmatically? Also keep in mind that you can simply change the scale property of the sprite to make it smaller. Though the texture will still be large and consume memory accordingly. Last alternative is to render the scaled down sprite to a render texture, save it, and create a new sprite from that.